# Difference between unreleased t and unreleased d

Tags: phonetics

If both *t* and *d* are unreleased, as in the words *let* and *led*, how do you differentiate between them? Are the different lengths of the short e sound in both words and the context in which they are used the only ways to tell which word is being used?

Comment: In addition to the shorter vowel before t, the t may have the glottis closed.

Comment: And the glottis may even close before the tongue reaches its target for the alveolar closure (for the [t]), resulting in the formant transitions not reaching values that are as extreme as they are before [d].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for very widely-spaced glottal pulses in the last 80 msc or so of [ɛ] in [lɛt], which is creaky voice on the vowel. You may also find that F1 and F2 are a bit higher in [lɛt]. (Pick a point defined from the beginning of the vowel, so that you aren't just measuring a consequence of the shortening of the vowel in [lɛt]).